# When will the Lua table.sort method become stable?

Tags: programming-languages, lua, stable-sort

I was just reading the official [Lua documentation on **Table.sort**](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-table.sort) and noticed that it says:

> "[Table.sort] algorithm is **not stable**; that is, elements considered equal by the given order may have their relative positions changed by the sort."

Any ideas when `Table.sort` will become stable in Lua?

Comment: No sort is pre-destined to become stable. It's a conscious choice and a potential performance/benefit trade-off. See [sorting in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

Comment: I don't use Lua, but if you want stable sort you can simply add another parameter position to all of the elements and then sort will do the trick.

Comment: Note: Lua is a language pretty much designed for a) simplicity and b) speed. Whenever there's a trade-off between complexity and simplicity, you can bet good money that Lua has chosen the latter.

Comment: I would not expect it to become stable because of the performance benefits of unstable sorting. But I would think it would make the language more robust if at some point there was an additional method like table.stablesort(table[, comp]) that would guarantee stability even if having a little worse performance.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure, but I think you're mixing up two completely different things:

[Stability of a sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) (which is meant in the Lua reference)

and

Software stability aka. "bug freeness".

Answer (score 6):

It won't, this is on purpose and best for performance.

Write your own if you really need a stable one.

Answer (score 1):

A stable sorting algorithm is slightly more expensive (in terms of processing power) than an unstable sort. An unstable sort is perfectly adequate for most applications.

Unless there is a specific plan to introduce a stable sort into Lua, I would assume that the sort function will stay the way it is.